# Python: "else:" invalid syntax error in Topcoder working environment?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

Error msg: Your code did not compile:
Invalid syntax on line 10 column 5
else:

Am I missing something obvious?

```
word = list(input("input: "))
w2 = word
cnt = 0
out = 0
again = True
while again:
    if cnt < len(word):
        word[cnt] = ord(word[cnt]) - 64
        cnt = cnt + 1
    else: 
        cnt = 0
        while cnt < len(w2):
            out = out + word[cnt]
            cnt = cnt + 1
        print(out)
        again = False
```

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: (Edited pasted code) The indentation in line 2 and onwards was just a mistake made when pasting code to stackoverflow. The code in Topcoder wasn't indented.

Comment: No, really, check it again. If you don't find anything, check for mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: @user2357112 That would raise a `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. @mle Could you please show the full traceback?

Comment: Replace all "\t" (tabs) for "    " (four spaces) on your IDE.
Or select all your code and try to identify if there are some tabs

Comment: @a_guest: You'd think so, but it's not always a TabError.

Comment: Thanks @AndreBarbosa , I replaced all tabs with spaces and the code compiled!

Comment: @mle You can set your IDE to always use `spaces` instead of `tabs` to avoid troubles. Check if your IDE has that option.